# In Ruby how do I search a string line by line and only show lines that begin with 1

Tags: ruby, ssh

What i am wanting to do is to ssh into a ubiquiti device, run `brctl showmacs br0` and only retrieve the mac addresses on the local port (1) for instance:

```
1     d4:ca:6d:ec:aa:fe       no                 0.05
```

would be printed/put/written-to-file because it begins with a 1 while:

```
2     4c:5e:0c:d5:ba:95       no                38.62
```

will not.

Comment: In the future, please include your code.

Comment: Are you asking how to automate this via ssh too?

Answer (score 0):

Strings respond to `[]`; so you could take your collection `@collection` and `:select` where `x[0] == '1'`.

```
only_ones = @collection.select{|x| x[0] == '1' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSHKit](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit) to run a remote command:

```
on 'ubiquiti.yourdomain.com' do
  output = capture(:brctl, 'showmacs br0')
  puts output.lines.select{|line| line.start_with? "1"}
end
```